# Milliseconds to the highest possible time value before reaching 0,xx

Tags: c#

I would like to write a converter from milliseconds to the highest possible time value before reaching a 0,x value.

Let me clarify this with examples.

Let's assume you have `1500ms` this should result in `1,5secs`, because its the highest possible digit value *not* resulting in `0,x`.

So different examples would be

```
10ms = 10,0ms
100ms = 100,0ms
1000ms = 1,0sec
10000ms = 10,0sec
100000ms = 1,6min
1000000ms = 16,0min
10000000ms = 2,7hours
```

(The method should more or less be endless, so from hours to days, to weeks, to months, to years, to decades and so on...)

Is there a .net method for this?

Comment: Fairly easy - define a list/dictionary of the lowest number of ms before a certain superunit goes below 1, then use that to apply the appropriate conversion

Comment: I would create a conversion method for each of the conversions you want to support (ms to sec, sec to min, min to hr, hr to days, etc), then create a method that calls the conversions in order. After each conversion, if the new value is less than 1, stop and return the previous value. Keep going till you reach the largest time span you want to support return the result. The TimeSpan class will help with all the converts up to years then you will need to do your own conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following

```cs
public static string ConversionMethod(UInt64 ms)
{
    // change output format as needed
    string format = "######.###";

    var cutoffs = new List<UInt64>() {
        1000, // second
        60000, // minute
        3600000, // hour
        86400000, // day
        604800000, // week = day * 7
        2592000000, // month = day * 30
        31536000000, // year = day * 365
        315360000000, // decade = year * 10
        3153600000000, // century = decade * 10 (100 years)
        31536000000000, // millenia = century * 10 (1000 years)
        31536000000000000 // megayear = year * 100000
        // 18446744073709551615 // UInt64 MaxValue
        // 31536000000000000000 // gigayear = year * 100000000
    };

    var postfix = new List<String>() {
        "second",
        "minute",
        "hour",
        "day",
        "week",
        "month",
        "year",
        "decade",
        "century",
        "millenia",
        "megayear"
    };

    // The above are listed from smallest to largest for easy reading,
    // but the comparisons need to be made from largest to 
    // smallest (in the loop below)
    cutoffs.Reverse();
    postfix.Reverse();

    int count = 0;

    foreach (var cutoff in cutoffs)
    {
        if (ms > cutoff)
        {
            return ((decimal)((decimal)ms / (decimal)cutoff)).ToString(format) + " " + postfix[count];
        }

        count++;
    }

    return ms + " ms";
}
```

Conversion for the fraction is a bit dirty, might want to clean that up. Also, you'll have to decide how you want to handle leap years (and leap seconds), etc.

Answer (score 1):

While not the final solution, maybe `TimeSpan` can help you achieve what you are looking for.
It is to be noted however, `TimeSpan` supports only up to `TotalDays`.

```cs
var timespan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500);
var seconds = timespan.TotalSeconds; // equals: 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the TimeSpan class is the closest thing that meets your need, but clearly it's not exactly what you want. My take on it would look something like this:

```
public static string ScientificNotationTimespan(int milliseconds)
{
    var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, milliseconds);
    var totalDays = timeSpan.TotalDays;
    if (totalDays < 7)
    {
        if (timeSpan.TotalDays > 1) return timeSpan.TotalDays.ToString() + " days";
        if (timeSpan.TotalHours > 1) return timeSpan.TotalHours.ToString() + " hours";
        if (timeSpan.TotalMinutes > 1) return timeSpan.TotalMinutes.ToString() + " minutes";
        if (timeSpan.TotalSeconds > 1) return timeSpan.TotalSeconds.ToString() + " seconds";
        return milliseconds.ToString() + "milliseconds";
    }

    var weeks = totalDays / 7;
    //How long is a month? 28, 29, 30 or 31 days?
    var years = totalDays / 365;
    if (years < 1) return weeks.ToString() + " weeks";
    var decades = years / 10;
    if (decades < 1) return years.ToString() + " years";
    var centuries = decades / 10;
    if (centuries < 1) return decades.ToString() + " decades";
    var millenia = centuries / 10;
    if (millenia < 1) return centuries.ToString() + " centuries";
    return millenia.ToString() + " millenia";
}
```

Comment: Actually, the millenia part will not work, as there are too many milliseconds in a millenium to be fit into an int.

Answer (score -1):

Here is solution for years, months using DateTime and Gregorian calendar (meaning leap years, calendar months). Then it uses the TimeSpan solution as already submitted.

```
static string ToMostNonZeroTime(long ms) {
    const int hundretsNanosecondsInMillisecond = 10000;
    long ticks = (long)ms * hundretsNanosecondsInMillisecond;
    var dt = new DateTime(ticks); 

    if((dt.Year - 1) > 0) { // starts with 1
        double daysToYear = (dt.DayOfYear - 1) * 1.0 / (DateTime.IsLeapYear(dt.Year) ? 366 : 365);
        daysToYear +=  dt.Year - 1;
        return $"{daysToYear:0.0} years";
    }
    if((dt.Month - 1) > 0) {
        double daysToMonth = (dt.Day - 1) * 1.0 / DateTime.DaysInMonth(dt.Year, dt.Month);
        daysToMonth +=  dt.Day - 1;
        return $"{daysToMonth:0.0} months";
    }
    // can use TimeSpan then:
    var ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ms);
    if(ts.TotalDays >= 1)
        return $"{ts.TotalDays:0.0} days";
    if(ts.TotalHours >= 1)
        return $"{ts.TotalHours:0.0} hours";
    if(ts.TotalMinutes >= 1)
        return $"{ts.TotalMinutes:0.0} minutes";
    if(ts.TotalSeconds >= 1)
        return $"{ts.TotalSeconds:0.0} seconds";
    return $"{ms} milliseconds";
}
```

It prints

```
100ms: 100 milliseconds
1000ms: 1.0 seconds
10000ms: 10.0 seconds
100000ms: 1.7 minutes
1000000ms: 16.7 minutes
10000000ms: 2.8 hours
100000000ms: 1.2 days
1000000000ms: 11.6 days
20000000000ms: 19.6 months
200000000000ms: 6.3 years
```

Have a look at https://ideone.com/QZHOM4

Comment: This is a bad use of `DateTime` - I very much doubt whether "years and months if you deem it to start at January 1st 1AD" is a useful measure.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I also doubt about that as I'm not sure about purpose of this formatting (some magic world?). Just a guess if it was our world.